# How to debug in runtime webpages with Python

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I would like to have a script that can retrieve the value of data using functions at the time of execution.

I want to debug functions of webpages that is being used. For example, when I go to the webpage, I can put 'breakpoints' in the browser (like Chrome) and get the functions in the console. My idea would be to do this using Selenium, but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: What language is the code you are debugging? Is this JavaScript loaded with the webpage? If so, you should use Chrome or Firefox dev tools. You don't need Python nor Selenium for this.

Comment: Yes, It's JavaScript. But, exists many many data that I want get and I think that is better with a script in Python that retrieve it.

Comment: @megnihuknu please read [mcve] and add your code trials data samples accordingly

Comment: @megnihuknu Scraping data from webpages is different than debugging code. We need more information about what you want to do in order to suggest the best way to proceed.

Comment: When I go to the page, I need consume some functions that retrieve some information. It’s only accessible with runtime execution and for it purpose, I need to put breakpoints in the source file of the webpage via browser(Chrome DevTools). I need that scripts put breakpoints automatically and get info like a console...